# R Casual Impact package - How to determine impact of Campaign 1 when Campaign 2 was also live during same period?

Tags: r, statistics, statsmodels, bayesian

I have a theoretical / stats related question. I've run the package in R and it's easy.
Question: How can I know the incremental impact of Campaign #1 during a period when Campaign #2 was also active during the same time period and in the same markets as Campaign #1?

Comment: Theoretical stat question should be asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.